# Sorting a XML file

Tags: xml

I have a XML file with data from satellite TV and Radio channels. This list has data about more than 3000 channels and is almost 80000 rows long. Per channel 18 rows of information. The second row gives the channel number. I want to change this numbers and than sort the list again. Is that possible and could someone tell me how to do it or can you give me a hint where to find help.
I have tried to do it in notepad++ and Excel, but I'm not a trained user and don't no haw to do it.

FYI this is a copy of one set:

```
<Service>
  <ChannelNo>303</ChannelNo>
  <ServiceName>BBC One Lon</ServiceName>
  <ServiceType>TV</ServiceType>
  <Scrambled>false</Scrambled>
  <SatId>5</SatId>
  <Frequency>10773</Frequency>
  <Sid>6301</Sid>
  <Tsid>2045</Tsid>
  <Oid>2</Oid>
  <AudioPid>5001</AudioPid>
  <VideoPid>5000</VideoPid>
  <PcrPid>5000</PcrPid>
  <ChildrenLock>false</ChildrenLock>
  <Skip>false</Skip>
  <HD>false</HD>
  <FavoriteNo>1</FavoriteNo>
</Service>
```

Comment: FYI: There is no rows in XML, there is only nodes.

Comment: What programming language are you using to do the sorting? If you're not interested in programming, you have come to the wrong site.

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT, it's:

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:for-each select="Service">
   <xsl:sort select="ChannelNo" data-type="number"/>
   <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```